# Way to convert image straight from URL to base64 without saving as a file in Python

Tags: python, base64, jpeg

I'm looking to convert a web-based image to base64. I know how to do it currently by saving the image as a .jpg file and then using the base64 library to convert the .jpg file to a base64 string.

I'm wondering whether I could skip out the step of saving the image first? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you share the code you have so far (downloading to a file and then converting), it will be easier for people to help you. As it is, I don't even know what library you want to use to fetch the file in the first place.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library:

```
import base64
import requests


def get_as_base64(url):

    return base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)
```

Comment: if i dont save image so how could i get url of particular image?

Comment: @rajlaxmi_jagdale : Couldn't the `url` be a **s3 link** maybe

Comment: base64 returns a bytes type so you may need to do another conversion to get a string type, for example ```base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content).decode('utf-8')```

Answer (score 6):

Since `requests` is not an official package, I prefer to use urllib.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import base64

base64.b64encode(urlopen("http://xxx/yyy/abc.jpg").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution::--

```
from base64 import b64encode
def url_to_base64(url):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    }
    return b64encode(requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=120).content).decode(
        "utf-8"
    )
```